# clearing session in cache and browser at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, caching, authentication

I want to disable the multilogin in to my website .

So i am creating a session in cache .

and i am checking before login if the session already present in cache if not i am creating a session and allowing him to signin. 
if session is already present i am throwing a error message that you are logged in some where else.

I am clearing the local and cache session in signout . all working fine but when the page expires for inactivity , the session at local is getting deleted but session in cache is remaining same . so even if i am trying to login from same browser its giving error as i am already logged in .

Here is my code 
in global.asax

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null &&
 HttpContext.Current.Session["MULTIPLELOGIN"] != null)
    {
        string sKey = Session["MULTIPLELOGIN"].ToString();
        string sRecruiter = HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey].ToString();
    }
```

in login

```
string sKey = oRecruiter.RecruiterId.ToString();
string sRecruiter = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey]);
if (sRecruiter == null || sRecruiter == String.Empty)
{
TimeSpan SessTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout, 0, 0);
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(sKey, sKey, null, DateTime.MaxValue, SessTimeOut,   System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
HttpContext.Current.Session["MULTIPLELOGIN"] = userid;
```

allowing login
    }
    else
    {
    or error message
    }

Please let me know how to expire both things at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
change the cacheitempriority to SessTimeOut, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal from NotRemovable

Answer (score 0):

Give cache expire time out and session time out same , than this may solve your problem

Comment: The session can be kept alive though, at which point the time out resets. You'd need to reset the cache time out too

Comment: Presently I am giving both same